# Using alternate unixODBC installation

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

I'm working in an environment that has unixODBC installed on a org-wide centrally mounted drive, but we (the actual developers) aren't allowed to install drivers or datasources in it. It's all backwards but I have to live with it.

Right now I'm trying to build a python app that connects to a mssql 2005 server from this unix enviro, so I obviously need some sql drivers!

I circumvented my lack of access to the the preinstalled unixODBC by reinstalled unixODBC on a portion of the drive that I have full control over. I've installed freeTDS and configured everything so that I can successfully connect to the server with isql -- great!

Now the only problem is, when I execute a line in my python program (which is using pyodbc) like:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.connect("DSN=<dsn_name>;UID=...;PWD=...", autocommit=True)
```

I get

```
 ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

I assume this is because pyodbc is still looking for the original unixODBC install and not my local one. So I was wondering:

How do I configure my scripts to look for my local unixODBC install instead of the one installed on the main drive

Answer (score 6):

pyodbc is tricky to install in custom setups. You need to edit the `setup.py` script to look for the unixODBC from your custom location by adding something like

```
settings['include_dirs'] = ['/opt/local/include']
settings['library_dirs'] = ['/opt/local/lib']
```

to `get_compiler_settings` function.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? I've never really messed with setup.py and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing.

Comment: Assuming you are using [pyodbc 2.1.11](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/source/browse/setup.py?name=2.1.11), add the rows I mentioned below line number 142. Just make sure the paths point to your custom installation directories.

Comment: Thx @eclaird, I've had this same issue on OS X, where Apples included iODBC just doesn't work for the MSSQL version I need to connect to. I've had problems getting pyodbc to build against a different odbc installation, but your solution worked like a charm =)

Comment: This still works with pyodbc 3.0.7 (I guess) for me replaced the opt by usr as I am more the brewish type ;-) and of course as in snorris answer change the libraries setting also to 'odbc' inside the elif sys.platform == 'darwin' section. After doing that, I can talk to PostgreSQL over ODBC.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the above answer - it got me editing the get_compiler_settings in setup.py to tell it not to use the default iodbc.

What worked for me (OS X 10.9, pyodbc 3.0.7) was:

```
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    # OS/X now ships with iODBC.
    #settings['libraries'].append('iodbc')

    # but I don't want to use iodbc, I want to use brewed unixodbc 
    settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is possibly because its looking in the global ini file. You can set the location it looks for the `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files by defining `ODBCSYSINI=/path/to/location/of/inifiles`